# How to place three figures side by side, but two figures are seen as subfigures with one main caption, and third figure as standalone

Tags: subfloats, minipage

I would like to place the figures as illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

The below code can place three figures side by side, but the third one on the right hand side becomes 1c (instead of 2). Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

```
 \begin{figure*}[tp!]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.315\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{\footnotesize 1a. \label{fig:1a} }
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1a.pdf}}
  \end{minipage}\quad
  \begin{minipage}{.315\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{\footnotesize 1b. \label{fig:1b}}
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}}
  \end{minipage}\quad
  \begin{minipage}{.315\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{\footnotesize 2. \label{fig:2}}
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/2.pdf}}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{\footnotesize Main caption here. }
  \label{fig:main}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Maybe nesting a `subfloatrow` environment  in a `floatrow`?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your hint. I have never used floatrow or subfloatrow. Would you mind to show an example? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two versions using the `subcaption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tp!]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.63\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1a.pdf}
    \caption{1a}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
    \caption{1b}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main caption here.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.315\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
    \caption{Main caption of the second figure}\label{fig:2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}


\begin{figure*}[tp!]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.63\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1a.pdf}
    \caption{1a}\label{fig:3a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
    \caption{1b}\label{fig:3b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.315\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
  \end{minipage}
  \medskip
  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.63\linewidth}
    \caption{Main caption here.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.315\linewidth}
    \caption{Main caption of the second figure}\label{fig:4}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is indeed pretty.