# How to place six figures in a special way

Tags: minipage, sidewaysfigure

My problem is an extension of [previously related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552497/how-to-place-three-figures-side-by-side-but-two-figures-are-seen-as-subfigures).

Now, I would like to place them as shown below. I fail to extend the previous answer :(. Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again with the `subcaption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tp!]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.63\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1a.pdf}
    \caption{1a}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
    \caption{1b}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1c.pdf}
    \caption{1c}\label{fig:1c}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1d.pdf}
    \caption{1d}\label{fig:1d}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main caption here.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.315\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/2a.pdf}
    \caption{2a}\label{fig:2a}
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/2b.pdf}
    \caption{2b}\label{fig:2b}
  \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Main caption of the second figure}\label{fig:2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are awesome. 

I have got one problem with the caption of subfigures. They are weirdly stretched. Any suggestion how to handle that?

Comment: What does weirdly stretched mean? Could you provide an example for such a caption?

Comment: I am sorry for that comment. It seems that "problem" has apparently vanished after I have rewritten the caption. Now, I can't recreate it (odd). Please ignore my comment. I greatly appreciate your help.