# Complex figure layout

Tags: subfloats

I want the following figure layout:

[image]

How it can be done?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552497/how-to-place-three-figures-side-by-side-but-two-figures-are-seen-as-subfigures

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure*}[tp!]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.63\linewidth}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1a.pdf}
                \caption{Subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
                \caption{Subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.315\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
            \caption{}\label{fig:2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}

    
\end{document}
```