# A common subcaption for two subfigures which are placed side by side

Tags: minipage, sidewaysfigure

Yet another question related to [How to place three figures side by side, but two figures are seen as subfigures with one main caption, and third figure as standalone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552497/how-to-place-three-figures-side-by-side-but-two-figures-are-seen-as-subfigures).

In this attempt, I intend to place a common subcaption on the left two subfigures instead of their individual subcaptions -- as illustrated below. Any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need the subcaption on this scenario? Both images seem to share the same subcaption as well as the same caption? What is the added value of the subcaption  here?

Comment: @leandriis Sorry, I made a mistake in uploading this figure. I am going to correct it. I have only 1 caption in this scenario, but I would like to have two subcaptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tp!]
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.63\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{figures/1a1.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{figures/1a2.pdf}
    \caption{1a}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}
\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.315\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/1b.pdf}
    \caption{1b}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main caption here.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much.