# making a table of subfigures with shared captions

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to make a table of figures like below. I used \subfloat but have no clue how I can make shared caption for subfigures (every rectangle is a figure). Any advice will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552497/how-to-place-three-figures-side-by-side-but-two-figures-are-seen-as-subfigures%5D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this (with the help of the `subcaption` package)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1a}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig1b}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.52\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig1b}
\caption{Caption 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill % maximize the separation
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2a}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig2b}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.52\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig2c}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig3a}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.52\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig3b}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig3b}
\caption{Caption 3}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill % maximize the separation
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig4a}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.52\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig4b}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth,height=.1\textheight]{fig4c}
\caption{Caption 4}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Overall caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 excellento mio moro

Comment: is it possible to do this with the subfig package?

Comment: @user3236841 - Short answer: I think so. Slightly longer answer: Please post a new query, in which you ask for a subfig-based solution. I'm afraid I simply don't know the `subfig` package well enough.